# Dual Boot: grub not working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, windows-10

I have searched for an answer to this problem and even though it is pretty similar to many other problems, i had no matched solution. I tried to dual boot my laptop from windows 10 to windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 server version .

However, whenever i try to start my machine it goes straight to ubuntu and none of the booting options goes to windows. Grub doesn’t even shows up. My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 14 series.

I have also tried to change the grub timeout from 0 to 100s, but it just shows a black screen for a 100s and boots into ubuntu.

Moreover, I have already tried both legacy and uefi booting options, uefi didn’t even start and legacy gives the output previouly mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not work well with grub for some strange reason.  Try Installing Grub 2 on the windows OS, if you can get there (maybe through start up, use you keyboard for boot option menu) and then go the Ubuntu side and in the Terminal type 'sudo update-grub' and it should find the windows side

Comment: I have already tried it, with no solution as well